Admin products page column not sorting
I import products to my woocommerce site, and all the imported products have an category called "external".
Note: All the external products have a "_ei_product" meta key with an "availability property that either outputs "InStock" or an empty string.
The endgoal is to add an "InStock" column to the dashboard admin product page and be able sort.
// Populate custom column with stock status
add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'display_stock_status_column', 10, 2);
function display_stock_status_column($column, $post_id) {
    if ($column == 'stock_status') {
        $ext_product_obj = get_post_meta($post_id, '_ei_product', true);

        if (is_object($ext_product_obj)) {
            $stock = $ext_product_obj->availability;

            if ($stock == 'InStock') {
                echo '<span style="color: green;">' . __('In Stock', 'ytl-domain') . '</span>';
            } else {
                echo '<span style="color: red;">' . __('Out of Stock', 'ytl-domain') . '</span>';
            }
        }
    }
}

// Make the "Stock Status" column sortable
add_filter('manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'make_stock_status_column_sortable');
function make_stock_status_column_sortable($columns) {
    $columns['stock_status'] = 'stock_status';
    return $columns;
}

Until this point I can already see the "Stock Status" column, and the rest of my code looks like this for the sorting logic:
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sort_stock_status_column');
function sort_stock_status_column($query) {
    if (!is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($query->get('orderby') == 'stock_status') {
        $query->set('meta_key', '_ei_product');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
        add_filter('posts_clauses', 'sort_by_stock_availability', 10, 2);
    }
}

// Custom sorting logic for stock availability
function sort_by_stock_availability($clauses, $query) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ($query->get('orderby') == 'stock_status') {
        $clauses['orderby'] = "
            CASE 
                WHEN {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value LIKE '%\"availability\":\"InStock\"%' THEN 1 
                ELSE 2 
            END, 
            {$clauses['orderby']}
        ";
    }

    return $clauses;
}

When I refresh the page, click on the "Stock Status" sort link, the sorting does not reflect correctly because I see "InStock" and "Out of stock" mixed.
How do I sort the products using the availability?
Tried to be as detailed as possible and hope this helps.

it looks like you've stored a PHP object in a post meta value, keep in mind this object gets converted into a string, and when it's converted back into an object you run into a large class of security issues ( object deserialisation attacks ). It also makes querying meta values much more complicated and in some cases makes reliable querying impossible, e.g. the situation you're in now and the need to manually adjust the SQL query via filters. Instead of a _ei_product meta field, it would have been easier and more performant to use multiple fields, e.g. _ei_product_availability

you are absolutely right, however, the initial work is done via third party plugin, so my hands are a bit tied on this one and I am having to work with what I have.

that doesn't stop it being changed, or for an additional post meta field that copies the value. A loop can find posts that don't have it set and update the post meta to whatever it needs to be, even if the sites been running for 10 years with millions of posts. If it's easier than what you've got it's worth investigating. A separate meta field would let you use standard WP_Query parameters as intended to do this, ensuring no breakage or weirdness ( e.g. if that filter got fixed it could be incompatible with ElasticSearch which is on many enterprise hosts ). btw Do you have the final SQL query?
